Hide bottom toolbar or disable download option in react-doc-viewer
I have integrated React-Doc-Viewer into my application to display DOCX files. I need to restrict users from downloading these files, but the React-Doc-Viewer includes a bottom toolbar that allows downloading. It doesn't seem to be a built-in prop to hide or disable this toolbar.
looking for a solution to either hide the bottom toolbar or restrict the download option for users.

I attempted to use CSS to hide the bottom toolbar, but since the document is displayed within an iframe, the CSS didn't have the desired effect.
